# Cloud Storage: Remove all files under a folder from a bucket gs://<bucket>/path/to/directory/2017-{01..07}*

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have 800 million files under gs:///path/to/directory/2017-{01..07}* to delete, use this multi-threading delete recursively

```
$ gsutil -m rm -r gs://<bucket>/path/to/directory/2017-{01..07}*
```

run it under bash would expand to `gsutil -m rm -r gs://<bucket>/path/to/directory/2017-01* gs://<bucket>/path/to/directory/2017-02* gs://<bucket>/path/to/directory/2017-03* ... gs://<bucket>/path/to/directory/2017-07*`

but it shows deletion speed at 550/s ; so, to delete all 800 millions files would need 16 days, is too slow, wonder is there a faster way?

Answer (score 1):

You could distribute the processing across multiple machines. For example, have scripts so

- machine1 does `gsutil -m rm -r gs://<bucket>/path/to/directory/2017-01*`
- machine2 does `gsutil -m rm -r gs://<bucket>/path/to/directory/2017-02*`
- etc.

That would give you ~12x speedup.
You could make it faster still if you shard the data to be deleted more ways.